# Load DLL at runtime

Tags: c++, c, windows, cuda, visual-studio-2012

I'm using the CUDA Driver API in a project. When I execute the project in a PC that doesn't have a NVIDIA GPU, it gives "nvcuda.dll was not found".

The problem is: this DLL is only distributed with the GPU driver, not like in the Runtime API where you can put the DLL needed with your executable. I need to load this DLL in runtime, and if it doesn't exist I will know that CUDA is not available. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Professional.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Seems like this is a [windows question](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: You'd hope that the API has some option to allow dynamic loading. Is there any documentation for that API? Also, I presume you have some fallback position in case the required CUDA DLL is not present?

Answer (score 1):

Windows provides [an API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175.aspx) (`LoadLibrary`) to load DLLs into memory at runtime. You provide a `LPCTSTR` (null terminated pointer to a const `TCHAR`) containing the name/path of the DLL you want to load. If you provide a relative path, Windows will scan `PATH` and the executable's current directory for the file. If you provide an absolute path, Windows will use that.

If `LoadLibrary` returns `NULL`, Windows couldn't find the file.

Comment: Yes, but since the DLL is loaded at runtime automatically, I would need a way to "tell" the compiler that I don't want it to load by itself. Because it tries anyway to load the DLL when I start the executable.

Comment: Ahh.  I see.  You may want to combine [delay-loading of the DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx) with manually loading it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a small "Launcher" app that will check if system meets your requirements and will launch the main application or display an error depending on the check results.
To check if a DLL is available you can use `LoadLibrary()` as previously suggested.